# Problem between hyperref, pdfx and kvsetkeys

Tags: errors, hyperref, pdf-a

I have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar
\end{document}
```

which results in an error when compiled with either pdflatex or lualatex:

```
(c:/Local/TeXLive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/l8uenc.def)

! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `pdftex,pdfa,pdfversion=1.4'.

See the kvsetkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.806  }
```

The problem is with line 794 in pdfx.sty (when compiling with luatex):

```
\hypersetup{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex}%
```

The arguments are defined at line 750 in pdfx.sty:

```
\def\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex{pdftex,pdfa,pdfversion=1.\thepdfminorversion}%
```

but it seems that `\hypersetup` is not able to parse them.
The pdfx.sty file states that:

```
[2016/05/03 v1.5.8 PDF/X and PDF/A support (CVR/HTH/RRM/PS)]
```

The other files are from TeXLive 2016.

Is there a simple fix for this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know that `pdfx` (1) should be loaded after `hyperref` (most packages should be loaded first), (2) is compatible with LuaTeX?

Comment: I don't understand your comment because (1) I am loading `pdfx` after `hyperref` and (2) pdfTeX errors the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `pdfx` load `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Foo Bar
\end{document}
```

Generally, `hyperref` should be loaded late - last excepting packages which specifically require it be loaded first.

Comment: The problem in the real example (not the simple one above) is that there were several packages trying to load `hyperref`. But thanks.

Comment: I solved it by letting `pdfx` load `hyperref` and calling `hypersetup` later to set other options.